# How to send text to the right and lined up with another division

Tags: html, css

I have the following code, and I'm trying to make the caption for my "DigDug" game to the right and horizontally in line with the game itself, so that essentially the caption is directly below the game and lined up perfectly, and I was wondering how to go about doing that? The id for the caption is "#DigCaption" and the id for the game itself is "#DigDug". Thank you so much for any help whatsoever!

```css
/*CSS file - Patrick White*/

body {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  /*vertical center*/
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", Palatino, Georgia, Serif;
  color: #02849D;
  /*dark navy blue*/
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  background: url('../Images/Black_Rainbow.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*boxing, borders, and padding*/
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  min-width: 1200px;
  min-height: 950px;
}

body.video_games {
  min-height: 1030px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Rockwell, Baskerville, Warnock, Serif;
  font-size: 225%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #02849D;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
}

h2,
h3 {
  font-family: Rockwell, Baskerville, Warnock, Serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.7%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 0.3em;
  margin: 0.35%;
}

.box {
  /*a class tag that I use for my div elements, since I didn't want this to apply for all of my div elements I made a class so that I can easily state whether or not it should apply*/
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 0.2em;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: #111111;
}

.float_left {
  float: left;
}

p {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00594D;
  border-width: 0.4em;
  margin: 1em;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 1.1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00594D;
  border-width: 0.4em;
  margin: 0.35em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

table {
  border: 0.2em solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

th {
  border: 0.15em solid black;
  padding: 0.35em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

td {
  border-width: 0.2em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  padding: 0.35em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:link {
  color: #31AEC5;
  /*dark blue*/
}

a:visited {
  color: #015261;
  /*darker blue*/
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #505050;
  /*grey*/
}

nav {
  clear: left;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.gamebutton {
  background-color: #707070;
  /*grey*/
  border: none;
  color: #02849D;
  /*bright blue*/
  width: 35%;
  height: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 400%;
  /*centers the text vertically*/
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.info {
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  float: left;
}

.temp {
  font-style: italic;
}

.game_name_caption_dig {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 17%;
}

.game_name_caption_block {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 17%;
}

#main {
  color: #008B8B;
  clear: left;
}

#overview {
  color: #7FFFD4;
}

#overview:first-letter {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
}

#DigDug {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0;
}

#DigCaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

#BlockGame {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 0;
}

#skipnav {
  position: relative;
  right: 8%;
  width: 10.5em;
}


/* navigation menu styles */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.7em;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 0.125em 0.5985243em;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* no underline */
  background-color: #55FA99;
  /* dark green */
  border: 0.14em solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 1em 1em;
  /* rounded corner */
  border-top-right-radius: 1em 1em;
  /* rounded corner */
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:focus {
  color: #014C65;
  background-color: #006E5F;
  /*medium green*/
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav_menu {
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/MyStyle.css" media="screen">
      <link rel="icon" href="Images/favicon-16x16.png" type="image/png">
      <title>Web Portfolio: Patrick White's Video Games Page</title>
   </head>
   <body class="video_games">
  <div class="box" id="skipnav">
     <a href="#main">Skip to main content</a>
  </div>
  <h1>Video Games</h1>
  <div class="nav_menu">
     <nav>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="Accesibility.html">Accessibility</a></li>
           <li><a href="Usability.html">Usability</a></li>
           <li><a href="Graphics.html">Graphics</a></li>
           <li><a href="JavaScript.html">JavaScript</a></li>
           <li><a href="Tools.html">Tools</a></li>
           <li><a href="Video.html">Video</a></li>
           <li><a href="Games.html">Video Games</a></li>
           <li><a href="Maps.html">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
  </div>
  <main id="main">
  <h2 class="game_name_caption_dig">Dig Dug</h2>
  <h2 class="game_name_caption_block">Bloxorz</h2>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
     <div id="DigDug">
        <iframe height="576" width="600" src="http://static.arcadespot.com/embed/dig-dug/"></iframe>
        <!--the validator says that there are errors in the above code because the iframe attribute is obsolete, but that actually is necessary in the source pulling from the embed so I can't change that on my end, since that will actually make the embed source not work-->
     </div>
     <div id="DigCaption">
        Click on the wrench to configure the controls! (If it starts automatically hit 
        enter)<br/>If it doesn't work ensure that you have the latest edition of flash, and that
        it's also enabled. Also these games don't work on computers with
        games blocked on them (ie. the school computers)
     </div>
     <div id="BlockGame">
        <iframe height="576" width="600"src="http://www.freeonlinegames.com/embed/142936"></iframe>
        <!--the validator says that there are errors in the above code because the iframe attribute is obsolete, but that is actually a part of the embed source, so I can't change that without the embed source not functioning-->
     </div>
  </main>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the edit! @MichaelCoker

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI will append a `.cropFrame` element to `#imgContainer` for each crop frame, so to target those, you can use `:nth-child()` selectors. To target your first one, use `.cropFrame:not(:last-child)` and to target the last one, `.cropFrame:last-child`.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#choice1").on('change', function() {
    $("#elements").hide();
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      var $img = $('<img />').attr({
        src: reader.result
      });

      $img.on('load', function() {
        $img.cropbox({
          width: 300,
          height: 300
        }).on('cropbox', function(event, results, img) {

        });
      });
      $('#imgContainer').append($img);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});

$(function() {

  $("#choice2").on('change', function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      var $img = $('<img />').attr({
        src: reader.result
      });

      $img.on('load', function() {
        $img.cropbox({
          width: 300,
          height: 300
        }).on('cropbox', function(event, results, img) {

        });
      });
      $('#imgContainer').append($img);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});
```

```css
.cropFrame:not(:last-child) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.cropFrame:last-child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/jquery.cropbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/jquery.cropbox.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/1.0.5/hammer.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id='imgContainer'>
    <div id='elements'>
      <input type='file' id='choice1'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type='file' id='choice2'>
</form>
```